Goldengate 21.3 MA from MySQL 8 to Oracle 19 auto_increment primary key sequence value not replicated
I am trying to migrated a DB from MySQL 8 to Oracle 19.  there are certain tables in MySQL that use the auto_increment feature in MySQL to generate the primary key when a record is entered.  When I perform the Initial Load in GG MA 21.3 it adds the data and increments the primary key Identity column sequence to a value based upon the number of rows in the table and not the sequence number pulled from MySQL.  Therefore if any data in the past had been deleted in a table in MySQL leaving the number of rows in the table below the the sequence number.  Then I migrate via GG it will leave a sequence value below the max value of the primary key column.  That won't work.  Now in January of this year I performed this migration and had no issues.  I had to rebuild my GG server since it was on RHEL7 and put it on RHEL8.  Besides that there has been no change.  I have run the sequence.sql script on my target and yet this issue keeps happening.  Any idea why or how I solve it?  Thanks in advance.
